# sourcing shell environmental variables from c++

Tags: c++, linux, macos

Let's say I want to spawn a process from a daemon (running as root) using exec() and fork(), and that I also want to impersonate a different user before spawning the process using seteuid() and setegid(). If I also want to inherit the environmental variables set for that particular user, what's the best way you can suggest to do so ? Is there also another way without invoking a /sbin/sh and/or sudo ?

Would like to do that either on Linux and on Mac OS X !

Thanks !

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17929414/how-to-use-setenv-to-export-a-variable-in-c/17929641#17929641

Comment: I know the setenv existance, I was meaning what's the best way to source what's already inside .bash_profile or whatever default user shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as "environmental variables set for that particular user". The variables are not stored in a list somewhere, they are set by programs run upon login. You will have to run the same scripts. So just `exec` a shell with `-l` (login shell) and have it run (with `-c`) the desired command you would have passed to `exec` before.

Note that this might still not replicate the entire environment. Some variables (`DISPLAY`, for example) are often set by programs which are run in another way.

---

To obtain the PID of the final child, make sure to use `exec` in the command passed with `-c`:

```
# sh -l -c "exec sleep 50" &
[1] 30331
# ps -a
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
30331 pts/1    00:00:00 sleep
```

Comment: and grab the default shell from the user profile (`getpwnam` or `getpwuid`)

Comment: in that way, I don't know the PID of the process I'm spawning with the shell so I do not have control over it, I need to setup a process detection to grab the child PID. Having the shell spawning "set" and dump and reset the variables with setenv may be a good option ?