# How to set environment variable using setenv

Tags: c++, linux, unix, environment-variables

I am trying to set env variables using setenv function. But unfortunately it doesn't work as expected.

```
int setNewEnvVariable(const std::string *varName, const std::string *value)
{
    setenv(varName->c_str(), value->c_str(), true);
    return this->VAR_ADDED;
}
```

It seems to work only when it wants. Sometimes I can change (replace) variable, but than it doesn't do any changes. I cannot add new variable at all. I have tried to use putenv. But it didn't help

I have found when it doesn't change existed variable. When I try to add new variable nonexistent yet. after this it doesn't add new variable , but in addition it doesn't change existed variable ,but before trying to add new variable everything worked.

I mean that before trying to add new var it accepts changing of existent for example PATH, but after passing nonexistent variable like PATH2323 , it stops to accept changing existed vars.

**EDIT**

I have checked return value it is 0 and errno also 0........ What is wrong with it ?

Comment: If `setenv()` is mis-behaving, report its return value.  What is it?  IOW, does it work when the return value is 0 and fail when return value is non-zero?

Comment: Can you write a runnable test case that shows the problem?

Comment: Are you expecting the environment variable to change in your shell, or just the process?  For example, are you trying to change PATH and expect that when the program exits, the PATH in your shell will change?  I don't think `setenv()` can do that.

Comment: this is not C code, so the C tag should be removed

Comment: this is a duplicate of: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17929414/how-to-use-setenv-to-export-a-variable-in-c>