# Add executable to PATH at run time

Tags: c, linux

My goal is to add a program path to PATH variable so a different part of program can launch it by merely specifying its name, like this

```
int main()
{
    system("export PATH=%PATH%;/home/user/Workspace/myproject/build/bin/mybinary");
    system("echo $PATH");// <-- the PATH is changed

    //a far place in code
    system("mybinary"); // <-- this should run the executable, but it can't find it
    return 0;
}
```

Is this even possible to be done?

Comment: Use `setenv` to set environment variables. For Windows it appears to be `_putenv`.

Answer (score 2):

In Linux, you can use `setenv()` and `getenv()` to achieve it, included in the standard library. An example would be:

```
int main () {
    char *path;
    
    path = getenv("PATH"); /* Gets current value of PATH */
    strcat(path, ":/path/to/binary"); /* Adds the new path at the end */
    
    if(setenv("PATH", path, 1)) { /* Override allowed as 3rd parameter is nonzero */
        /* Handle error */
    }
}
```

Note: as said [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17929641/15380874) `setenv()` can't export variables to the calling process, only to itself and any new child created with `fork()`.